# Get a user's group memberships from Active Directory

Tags: .net, windows, active-directory

How can I about getting a user's group memberships from AD, preferably using the same pattern as I use to get the user's Department property, as below?  I have found several examples, but the intersecting set of all example techniques is quite small, and lacks the tightness and simplicity of this Department query:

```
        var adServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adServer"] ?? "localhost";
        var remoteRoot = new DirectoryEntry(GetRootPath(adServer));
        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(remoteRoot, string.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", shortUserName));

        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Department");
        SearchResult result = null;
        result = searcher.FindOne();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you on .NET 3.5 ? If so, it's very easy:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

string userName = "yourUser";

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);

PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

Find your user, and then call the `.GetAuthorizationGroups()` on your user principal - that returns all groups the user belongs to, including his primary group, and any nested group memberships.

Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) for more new goodness in .NET 3.5 when it comes to dealing with AD.

In .NET 2.0, things are a lot messier...

Comment: Thanks.  That's half working, but I get an error "Can't access domain info" (something like that) when I call GetAuthorizationGroups()

Comment: did you specify your NetBIOS domain Name when constructing the principal context? E.g. "YOURDOMAIN", instead of "yourcompany.com" ?