# Determine nested groups of WindowsIdentity instance

Tags: .net, windows, security, identity

Say i have an instance of `WindowsIdentity` and want to get groups it's a member of. I use the following code to obtain the list:

```
  WindowsIdentity identity = null;
  // get identity here
  identity.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Select(x => x.Value);
```

i get something like this:

```
 "BUILTIN\\Administrators"
 "BUILTIN\\Users"
 "NT AUTHORITY\\INTERACTIVE"
 "CONSOLE LOGON"
```

I have a local group (say, `MYSPECIALGROUP`) that has `BUILTIN\\Administrators` as its member. `MYSPECIALGROUP` is not returned in the sample above. How do i get *all* groups including the nested ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Get a user's group memberships from Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974023/get-a-users-group-memberships-from-active-directory)

As the answer to that question explains, `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace is what you need:

```
// get the user identity / roles
PrincipalContext pCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
    Settings.Default.Domain,          // domain
    Settings.Default.DomainReadUser,  // user to access AD with 
    Settings.Default.DomainReadPass); // password of that user

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pCtx, 
    User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last()); // Windows Auth current user

// this will have all of the security groups, even nested ones
IEnumerable<Principal> userRoles = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

Since you seem to be doing local machine users/groups, and with your WindowsIdentity variable, you would want to change the first few lines to:

```
PrincipalContext pCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pCtx, 
    identity.Name.Split('\\').Last());
```

See also: [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)